# VBA to return offset cell value based on data validated dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, validation, drop-down-menu, vlookup

New to VBA...

I have an invoice template with a data validation dropdown in Sheet1!A10 with the list location in Sheet3!B2:B4

I'm looking for help with returning the value in the Sheet3!A2:A4 based on the dropdown selection (Sheet3!B2:B4) in order to save a copy of the file with the offset values from the dropdown.

This is what I have so far based on search results, but I know I'm missing something somewhere

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
  Dim custlist As String
  Dim custname As String
  Dim path As String
  Dim filename As String

  custlist = Sheets(1).DropDowns(Range("A10:C10"))
  custname = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(custlist, Sheet3.Range("a:b"), 1, False)
  path = "C:\Users\files" 
 filename = custname 

  Sheet1.Copy

With ActiveWorkbook
.Sheets(1).Name = "Invoice"
.SaveAs filename:=path & filename, FileFormat:=51
.Close
End With
End Sub
```

I don't know how to set the the value of *custname* based on the dropdown selection *custlist*.

Comment: What is `Sheets(1).DropDowns`?

Comment: @BigBen That is were the dropdown is within the invoice. Like I said, I'm new to VBA and I am try to self teach (with help from here of course). So I was just trying all different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read the value of a cell with a data validation dropdown as a normal one.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FileSaveAs()
    Dim custList As String
    Dim custName As String
    Dim sPath As String
    custList = Sheet1.Range("A10").Value
    sPath = "C:\Users\files\"
    If Len(custList) > 0 Then
        For Each c In Sheet3.Range("B2:B4")
            If StrComp(c.Value, custList, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                custName = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If Len(custList) > 0 Then
        Sheet1.Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Sheets(1).Name = "Invoice"
            .SaveAs filename:=sPath & custName, FileFormat:=51
            .Close
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I was over complicating things. I learn every time I come here! Thanks again.